# What is the kind of Void?

Tags: haskell

Seeing as the type of `Void` is uninhabited, can it be regarded as a type "constructor"? Or is this just a quick "hack" to be able to safely disregard / disable functionality and am I looking too deep into this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

0 was once not considered to be a number.  ["How can nothing be something?"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28number%29#Greeks_and_Romans)  But over time we came to accept 0 as a number, noticing its properties and its usefulness.  Today the idea that 0 is *not* a number is as absurd as the idea that it was one 2,000 years ago.

`Void` is a type the same way 0 is a number. Its kind is `*`, just like all other types.  The similarity between `Void` and 0 runs quite deep, as Tikhon Jelvis's answer begins to show.  There is a strong mathematical analogy between types and numbers, with `Either` playing the role of addition, tupling `(,)` playing the role of multiplication, functions `(->)` as exponentiation (`a -> b` means b<sup>a</sup>), `()` (pronounced "unit") as 1, and `Void` as 0.

The number of values a type may take is the numeric interpretation of the type.  So

```
Either () (Either () ())
```

is interpreted as

```
1 + (1 + 1)
```

so we should expect three values. And indeed there are exactly three.

```
Left ()
Right (Left ())
Right (Right ())
```

Similarly,

```
(Either () (), Either () ())
```

is interpreted as

```
(1 + 1) * (1 + 1)
```

so we should expect four values.  Can you list them?

Coming back to `Void`, you can have, say, `Either () Void`, which would be interpreted as 1 + 0.  The constructors of this type are `Left ()`, and `Right v` for every value `v` of type `Void` -- however there are no values of type `Void`, so the only constructor for `Either () Void` is `Left ()`.  And 1 + 0 = 1, so we got what we expected.

**Exercise**: What should the mathematical interpretation of `Maybe a` be?  How many values of `Maybe Void` are there -- does this fit with the interpretation?

### Notes

- I am ignoring partiality in this treatment, pretending Haskell is total.  Technically `undefined` can have type `Void`, but we like to use [fast and loose](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html) reasoning which ignores these.
- The way `void` is used in C-based languages is actually much more like Haskell's `()` than Haskell's `Void`. In Haskell, a function returning `Void` can never return at all, whereas in `C` languages a function returning `void` can return, but the return value is uninteresting -- there's only one thing it could be so why bother?

Comment: Very interesting answer! Is there a book or reference behind the magic/math here?

Comment: Chris Taylor has a great set of blog posts about this: [The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/).

Comment: @tinlyx I think a good search keyword for this is "polynomial types" (there's also "polynomial functors", but I can't yet say whether those are related).

Comment: what a great answer

Answer (score 42):

It's a type of kind `*` just like `Int`, `Bool` or `()`. It just happens to have 0 values instead of 1 or 2 or more.

It's not a hack but rather a fundamental part of Haskell's type system. It plays the role of 0 to `()`'s 1 and, if we look at types as propositions, `Void` corresponds to the proposition "false". It's also an identity to sum types (`Either`) just like `()` is an identity to product types: `Either a Void` is isomorphic to `a`.

In practice, it often acts as a dual of `()`; the best example of this I've seen is in [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/Pipes-Core.html#t:X) where `()` is used to tag things that don't take inputs and `Void` (named `X`) is used to tag things that don't produce outputs. (See [Appendix:Types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html#g:9) in the tutorial.)

It *is* a way to mark things as impossible or missing, but it is by no means a hack.

Comment: Wow, I finally realise what object orientation sounds like to people who don't program.

Comment: To be able to mark this question as closed, I've selected one of the suggested answers as a definitive one, but that does not mean your answer was any less informative. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Pharap: Oh yeah, it was a bit more terse than I usually write, but I didn't feel like writing more this time :P.

Comment: While the use of `Void` in `pipes` to mark things that don't produce outputs is perfectly reasonable, I don't think the use of `()` to mark things that don't take inputs is reasonable. `()` is a sort of "tick" in that context, a valid thing to wait for and then throw away. In **Hask**, `Void` is an initial object and `()` is a final object. In a non-trivial pipe category, there are no initial or final objects.

Answer (score 17):

Another angle on this question: suppose I asked you to write a guaranteed-terminating function of type `a -> b`:

```
aintGonnaWork :: a -> b
aintGonnaWork a = _
```

As hopefully you can tell, it's impossible to write such a function.  It follows from this that the type `a -> b` has no defined values.  Note also that the kind of `a -> b` is `*`:

```
(->)   :: * -> * -> *
a      :: *
b      :: *
---------------------
a -> b :: *
```

And there we have it: a type of kind `*`, built from "vanilla" Haskell elements (no "hacks"), but which nevertheless has no defined values.  So the existence of types like `Void` is already implicit in "vanilla" Haskell; all that the explicit `Void` type does is provide a standard, named one.

I'll close with a simple implementation of the `Void` type in terms of the above; the only extension necessary is `RankNTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Void = Void (forall a b. a -> b)

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd (Void f) = f f
```

Comment: As I explain in my answer, it takes no extensions to write the classic `data Void = Void !Void`.

Comment: For a rank-2 solution, the simplest is `newtype Void = Void {absurd :: forall a. a}`.

Answer (score 2):

Luis Casillas showed that a polymorphic type can be uninhabited in vanilla Haskell. But there are also uninhabited *monomorphic* types. The classic one looks like this:

```
data Void = Void !Void

absurd :: Void -> a
absurd (Void x) = absurd x
```

Imagine trying to construct something of type `Void`.

```
void :: Void
void = Void _
```

You need something of type `Void` to fill the hole. Since that's the whole point of `void`, the only sensible choice is

```
void :: Void
void = Void void
```

If the `Void` constructor were lazy, that would be a cyclical structure `Void (Void (Void ...))`. But since it's strict, `void` can be written equivalently as

```
void = void `seq` Void void
```

which is obviously not going to fly.