# How many distinct values does the type have?

Tags: haskell, types

I have a given type

```
type Foo = Either (Bool, ()) (Maybe Ordering)
```

I know that the type `Bool` has two distinct values: `True` and `False`.

Assuming that, is it correct that the following type:

```
type Foo = Either (Bool, ()) (Maybe Ordering)
```

has `2+2+1+2+3 = 10` distinct values, considering how the other types are built:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
data Ordering = EQ | LT | GT
```

Comment: It looks like you're just adding up the number of constructors of each type but you can't do that - `(Bool, ())` has 2 inhabitants (2 * 1) not 3 (2 + 1). Similarly a `Maybe Ordering` has 4 inhabitants not 5.

Comment: Can you write down what you think all the possible values are and count them? There aren't too many to go through.

Comment: I am not sure, are ```(Bool, ())``` and ```(Maybe Ordering)``` the type parameter a and b for the data type Either? If so, the distinct values of ```Bool```l are ```True and False``` => 2 and ```()``` has no further distinct values so ```()``` is a value itself, added up, we get 3 distinct values. The second parameter ```(Maybe Ordering)``` has also 3 distinct values because the ```Ordering``` data type is a parameter for ```Maybe``` and ```Ordering``` itself  has 3  distinct values. That means all together we get 6 distinct values types? Maybe I missunderstood what distinct values really mean

Comment: You say that `Bool` has exactly two values. That's correct. How many for `(Bool, ())`, then? Try to solve this bottom-up.

Comment: Hint: `Either`, `Maybe` and `Ordering ` are **sum** types, whereas `(,)` is a **product** type. Those names mean something about the number of elements they have ;)

Comment: If you add the number of values of `Bool` and the number of values of `()` you get the number of values for `Either Bool ()`, not for `(Bool, ())`. For the latter, you need to multiply, not add.

Comment: Ah as @Lee mentioned there are 2*1 + 4 = 6 distinct values and I forget to add one distinct value (Nothing) in my longer comment above. I understand a bit more now !

Comment: There is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29953369/7096763) on an other SO question that addresses this exact issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have:

```
        type Foo = Either (Bool, ()) (Maybe Ordering)
```

`Either` carries either a value of the one type, or a value of the other type:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
    |Either a b|  =  |a| + |b|

        |Foo| = |(Bool, ())| + |Maybe Ordering|
```

`(,)` carries two values, each of its corresponding type, so for each specific `a` type value there are `|b|` choices of a specific `b` type value:

```
data (,) a b = (a , b)
    |(a,b)| = |a| * |b|

        |Foo| = |Bool| * |()| + |Maybe Ordering|
```

`Bool` is like `Either () ()`:

```
data Bool = False | True
    |Bool|  =  1  +  1 

        |Foo| = (1 + 1) * |()| + |Maybe Ordering|
```

`()` has just one value, `()`:

```
data () = ()
    |()| = 1

        |Foo| = (1 + 1) * 1  +  |Maybe Ordering|
```

`Maybe a` is like `Either () a`:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
    |Maybe a|   =   1  +  |a|

        |Foo| = (1 + 1) * 1  +  (1 + |Ordering|)
```

`Ordering` is like `Either () (Either () ())`:

```
data Ordering = EQ | LT | GT
    |Ordering| = 1 +  1 +  1

        |Foo| = (1 + 1) * 1  +  (1 + (1 + 1 + 1))
```

You do the math. :)

Comment: Well put together explanation.